# I need to rewrite as a join Optimized Mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

I really need some help on this query. I'm having like 5 select subqueries.

--

```
select s.id,
       s.user_id,
       m.photo                         as profile_photo,
       CONCAT(m.name, ' ', m.lastname) as fullname,
       s.title,
       s.date,
       s.photo,
       s.city,
       (select count(c.id)
        from   s_comments as c
        where  c.story_id = s.id)      as comments_sum,
       (select SUM(important)
        from   s_user_votes as v1
        where  v1.story_id = s.id)     as v_important,
       (select SUM(fun)
        from   s_user_votes as v2
        where  v2.story_id = s.id)     as v_fun,
       (select SUM(interesting)
        from   s_user_votes as v3
        where  v3.story_id = s.id)     as v_interesting,
       (select SUM(boring)
        from   s_user_votes as v4
        where  v4.story_id = s.id)     as v_boring
from   stories as s,
       members as m
where  s.user_id = m.id
order  by v_interesting desc,
          v_boring asc,
          s.date desc
limit  50;
```

--

Answer (score 0):

4 of the sub queries were just to retrieve aggregates for different columns in the same table (`s_user_votes`) so these were easy to consolidate into a single `join`.

I used a `left [outer] join` so the original semantics were preserved (if a story has no user votes it should still appear in the results).

The other subquery is on a different table (`s_comments`). I have put that into a derived table rather than joining onto it directly to ensure that at most only 1 row per story is returned.

This will prevent the issue where a story with multiple comments or multiple user votes would cause a multiplication in the number of rows returned messing up the `SUM` calculation.

I also added a `GROUP BY` on story `id` (In MySQL this is sufficient other RDBMSs would need you to list out all the non aggregated columns)

```
select s.id,
       s.user_id,
       m.photo                         as profile_photo,
       CONCAT(m.name, ' ', m.lastname) as fullname,
       s.title,
       s.date,
       s.photo,
       s.city,
       c.comments_sum,
       SUM(v.important)                as v_important,
       SUM(v.fun)                      as v_fun,
       SUM(v.interesting)              as v_interesting,
       SUM(v.boring)                   as v_boring
from   stories as s
       join members as m
         on s.user_id = m.id
       left join (select story_id,
                         count(story_id) as comments_sum
                  from   s_comments
                  group  by story_id) as c /*<-- Can't remember if "as" needed here in MySQL*/
         on c.story_id = s.id
       left join s_user_votes as v
         on v.story_id = s.id
group  by s.id
order  by v_interesting desc,
          v_boring asc,
          s.date desc
limit  50;
```

Comment: My only addition to your SQL would be to take the 4 SUM() from the S_User_Votes table into ITS own subquery and left join EXACTLY like you did with the S_Comments query.